# Analyzed by or analyzed with?

Tags: prepositions

- > The data were analyzed **by** the ANOVA method.
- > The data were analyzed **with** the ANOVA method.

Which one is more appropriate?

Comment: Note: "Analyzed by/with ANOVA" is redundant. You could say `The data were analyzed by variance (ANOVA).` (Incidentally, *by* is acceptable here, just as in "the samples were ordered by length," even though I voted, mostly for other reasons, for the answers below that warned against using *by*.)

Answer (score 2):

Using "analyzed *by*" is a little off here, since it implies that the ANOVA method has agency, that is, is capable of doing things on its own. So if you have a computer program that runs more or less independently to analyze data, this would make sense, but otherwise it's not quite right.

Using "analyzed *with*", though, is fine. The method is a large part of the process, but the one doing the analysis is really the person (or people) who apply the method. You could also say "analyzed *using*" for essentially the same meaning.

Comment: Would prefer "using" or "by using". Thanking you Nathan. A great day ahead.

Answer (score 1):

> The data were analyzed **by** the ANOVA method.

This uses the passive to show that *ANOVA method* is the agent of the action. (We can think in this case that the *ANOVA method* is a computer software.)

> The data were analyzed **with** the ANOVA method.

This also uses the passive, but it doesn't mention who or what thing did the action, the only thing you know is with the help of the *ANOVA method*, the data was analyzed.

Comment: @hmmn I've edited. It's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

The prepositions by and with can be used to talk about the method that's used to do something.

So you can say  "analyzed by the ANOVA method or analyzed with the ANOVA method", without any difference in meaning. Look at the following sentence listed under 'by' in McMillan Dictionary:

Reading is taught by traditional methods here.

I think you can replace "by" with "with" in the sentence.